# How can I add a new document to Docpad's database using the API?

Tags: database, docpad

Is there a way to programmatically update or add a new document or file to Docpad? 
I noticed in the Docpad's [history file](https://github.com/bevry/docpad/blob/master/HISTORY.md) that we have `addFile`, `addDocument`, `addModel`  available. I also saw `createDocument` in the tumblr plugin. I'm building a simple CMS on top of Docpad and I would like to update Docpad's database without triggering a rendering of the complete site which would be too slow.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827193/how-can-i-exclude-files-to-being-regenerated-by-docpad